# How to send email through SMTP protocol using CSharp and proxy network?

Tags: c#, proxy, smtp, smtpclient

I am working in a project , In which i will be retrieving the password of the user from the database and mail it to the user email id. For this i am using SMTP protocol. But i was not able to send the mail from my application.
I am using proxy network in the company in which i am working.
I think using proxy network is the reason for getting error while sending the email.
Is there any alternate solution for sending the email through SMTP protocol from a proxy network.

**code used.**

```
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
        mm.Subject = "Password Recovery";
        mm.Body = string.Format("Hi {0},<br /><br />Your password is {1}.<br /><br />Thank You.", username, password);
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = "sender@gmail.com";
        NetworkCred.Password = "senderpassword";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        lblMessage.Text = "Password has been sent to your email address.";
```

**Exception image:**

[image: Exception:]

Comment: What error are you getting? Exception details?

Comment: also unrelated, but important. I hope that is a newly reset password you are sending to the user, and not their actual password.  You should not be storing passwords in plain text, or even encrypted.  Best practices state passwords need to be salted and hashed

Answer (score 0):

you may set WebRequest

```
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1",8580);
```